# Angularjs accessing variable in one function from another function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to access a variable in one function from another function. My code goes similar to this

NOTE: I get value for submitData.alcohol in other part of my code.

```
angular.module('app',['ui.router'])
 .controller('infoCtrl',['$scope','$http',functioninfoCtrl($scope,$http){
    var result;
    $scope.one = function(){
      if(submitData.alcohol=='1'){
        result = 'Yes';
      }else{
        result = 'No';
       }
    };

    $scope.two = function(){
       console.log(result);
    }
}]);
```

But I  get a 'undefined' in my log. How can I fix this?

Comment: use a service, this why service have been created

Comment: nooo need to use a service inside the same controller. it is overkill. a var is more than enough

Comment: are you sure that you call $scope.one function ? put a log inside it

Comment: i'm calling $scope.one function in the two function.. I forgot to include in this.. I have edited the question.. Still I get undefined error

Comment: What is submitData? As in your current posted code's context **it is undefined**. Not result.

Comment: nothing wrong with submitData.. it's coming from a separate part..

Comment: @crazydroid can you confirm? Again with logging the value as if this has a dependency then you have to inject it.

Comment: yes..result is variable that i'm getting undefined as

Answer (score 0):

There could be couple of reasons:

1. Your `$scope.one` could be async function, so your `console.log(result)` is being printed undefined before the `$scope.one` gets complete.
2. Your function `$scope.one` is never called?

   ```
   var result = "";    
   $scope.one = function() {    
       if (submitData.alcohol == '1') {    
           result = 'Yes';
       } else {
           result = 'No';
       }        
   };

   $scope.two = function() {    
       $scope.one();
       console.log(result);    
   }
   ```

   **Update: Use Promises**

Your `$scope.one` function here

```
$scope.one = function(param) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

    YourAPICall(param, function(data) {            
      deferred.resolve(data);
    });    
   return deferred.promise;
};
```

Your `$scope.two` function here

```
 $scope.two = function(){
     $scope.one(param).then(function (data) {
         console.log("data", data);//check for your condition here                  
     });
 }
```

Comment: I think the reason could be the first one.. if it's the case, how can I fix this?

Comment: i'm sorry I did not understand. can you please help

Comment: what is YourAPICall should be?

Comment: The API call you are making @CraZyDroiD or can you post the complete actual code to look at

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the variable to the scope:

```
var $scope.result = '';
```

and always refer to it this way, inside the if clause:

```
if(submitData.alcohol=='1') {
    $scope.result = 'Yes';
} else {
    $scope.result = 'No';
}
```

and conosole.log:

```
console.log($scope.result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of 'result' change it to '$scope.result'

```
if (submitData.alcohol == '1') {

     $scope.result = 'Yes';
} else {

     $scope.result = 'No';
}
```

Another thing to mention in your problem is you have to make sure that problem one has been done before the result is actually returned. Can you post your whole code,, so we can take a closer look? Or try to give a demo in plunk or jsfiddle

Comment: you don't have to do this. $scope is for sharing data with the view. his result variable is declared outside the function so it's ok. i think the function is never called

Comment: Yeah, I agree but using $scope.result will make his life a lot easier especially when he just wants ro return the results. He won't even need the second result if he applied $scope